# genealogy pedigree chart

Tags: algorithms, terminology, recurrence-relations

What is the simple expansion of a (simple) genealogy pedigree chart, where each person (only) has 2 parents? What is that called? Is it an arithmetic progression, or a geometric progression? You start with yourself. You have 2 parents. They have each got 2 parents, etc. By the time the chart shows your great grand parents, all 8 of them, there is a total of 15 people on the chart.   I say simple, because in reality people often have more than one spouse; and a pedigree chart really represents, for each couple, family clusters from which only one child is shown (The Important One! Your own ancestor, ha, ha.). But for that simple pyramid - increasing by 2's for each person - is that arithmetic or geometric progression?
Thank you for your help.
Damaris Fish, Central Point, Oregon
damarisfish@gmail.com

Is it Pascal's Triangle, sort of? 
Linear recurrence relation?
I just want the right word....

Comment: look under "binary tree". For example the wikipedia article about "binary tree" has a part called "properties" where you should find your answer.

Comment: And to answer more precisely to your question: the number $n$ of nodes for a tree of depth $h$ is given by $n=2^{h+1} -1$.

Comment: There is no need to give us your e-mail or home address...

Comment: From Wikipedia - A perfect binary tree...  and [genealogy] trees go in the opposite direction from usual (root at bottom). My problem is that as an adult, trying to explain interest in family history to a younger person, they think mathematically. It is worse than that tho', because "typical" families are not typical anymore. People, yes, may have two biological parents (even one unknown, or two unknown), but there are other relationships that count as parents, too. Plus keeping track of descendants and collateral lines -> and after a while you're headed for big data!